# Why can't I install KVM?

Tags: debian, virtualization, hardware, kvm-virtualization, vdi

I'm running on an Intel i7 930. I'm new to virtual machines and linux. I'm trying to learn how to use and install KVM. So I used VirtualBox to install Debian 6 64-bit. So I got the VirtualBox up. I typed in

```
grep "vmx" /proc/cpuinfo
```

But nothing return, and I read somewhere that if it don't return anything then I wont be able to install KVM, or run hardware virtualization.

My question, if I'm able to run VirtualBox and VMware shouldn't I be able to install kvm too?

Comment: Have you enabled Intel VT support in your system's BIOS?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm trying to run nested virtualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question properly you are trying to run KVM on a Virtual Linux Machine from within VirtualBox.  Which no one has seem to address in your previous answer/comments.

VirtualBox does not currently support nested virtualization so the virtual cpu that's being exposed to your virtual Linux machine doesn't support VT.  There are hypervisors that do support nested virtualization but it's not really something that's advised.

Comment: Yes that what I was trying to say. Didn't know it was called "nested virtualization". Since you don't recommend hypervisors, which do you recommend that support nested virtualization?

Comment: @user101699 If you remove the "accepted" on my answer, I will delete my incorrect answer.  +1 to this answer -- I have misread the question multiple times.

Comment: Right now I think the only ones that support this are Xen and newer versions of VMWare Fusion and Workstation.  http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_FAQ_Design_and_in_Depth#Nested_Xen and